# How can I grab multiple information from a table on a website using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to figure out how to pull multiple information that I want from the https://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/ website

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

for item in soup.select("table td"):
    if "Undeclared" in item.text:
        brand = item.find_parents()[0].select("td")[1].text
        reason = item.text
        print(brand,reason)
```

How do I get the brand_link from the html?

Comment: I suggest, at the places where you say "recall", consider whether you mean "recall row" or "table cell" and edit accordingly to clarify. Especially the final bit where you say that your code "pulls all recalls that have :". There's missing words there too. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is what your expected output was:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

for item in soup.select("table td"):
    if "Undeclared" in item.text:
        brand = item.find_parents()[0].select("td")[1].text
        reason = item.text
        print(brand,reason)
```

Partial Output:

```
N/A   Undeclared Milk
Colorado Nut Company and various other private labels   Undeclared milk
All Natural, Weis, generic   Undeclared milk
Dilettante Chocolates   Undeclared almonds
Hot Pockets   Undeclared egg, milk, soy, and wheat
Figiâs   Undeclared Milk
Germack   Undeclared Milk
```

When you want to get the links to the brand name as well, you can do something like below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = "https://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

for item in soup.select("table td"):
    if "Undeclared" in item.text:
        brand = item.find_parents()[0].select("td")[1].text
        brand_link = urljoin(url,item.find_parents()[0].select("td")[1].select("a")[0]['href'])
        reason = item.text
        print("Brand: {}\nBrand_link: {}\nReason: {}\n".format(brand,brand_link,reason))
```

Output:

```
Brand: N/A  
Brand_link: https://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/ucm587012.htm
Reason: Undeclared Milk
```

Comment: All the desired items within the table are finally stored in `td` tag. When you create a conditional statement to reach the data started with `Undeclared`, you may notice that they are in 4th `td` tag. So, when you want to get the brand name you need to revert back to reach the concerning `td` tag. However, `tr` is the parent of each `td` tag. So, when you locate your first search which is `Undeclared` then you need to get back to it's parent which is `tr` and do the next search for 2nd `td` tag in which brand names are embedded. Hope that helps. Be sure to mark this as an answer.

Comment: Awesome! Quick question: The brand name is also a link. If I wanted to grab that link, how would that work?

Comment: Try this `brand_link = item.find_parents()[0].select("td")[1].select("a")[0]['href']`.

Comment: So when I do that, I get back something like this: /Safety/Recalls/ucm586430.htm is there any way to get the actual link which would be https://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/ucm583556.htm

Comment: Sure. As soon as im near my pc i will let you know. I wrote this text from mobile.

Comment: No problem! I'm thinking there is a way to append https://www.fda.gov to the link?

Comment: See the edited part, I've already added the requested portion.

Comment: Thanks so much!! That is awesome :)